# How to see if function is superpolynomial?

Tags: functions

Is the function $f(n) = \prod_{x=2}^{n} log(x)$ greater than $n^c$ for any $c<\infty$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}=\ln(n+1)$ diverges as $n\to\infty$, $f$ is not only superpolynomial but superexponential.